# How build tree diagram in Vue

Tags: vue.js, treeview

I need to build a tree diagram in my Vue app like on the picture below depending on some data. It needs to be customizable. For example, I can add avatars, buttons, text to nodes as DOM elements. I find good library Vue.D3.tree, but it's not customizable. I can't find a good library for this. And I don't know how to write the same library myself. How can I solve this problem? Maybe you know libraries to help with this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.
[vue-organization-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-organization-chart)